# Decrease CPU usage or give priority

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I have a i3 2nd gen system with nvidia 1GB graphics card and running ubuntu .
The cpu usage becomes 99% when i run a 3D simulator and other OpenGL 2D application and i acquire the mouse movement data from another program but the mouse movement is slowed due to too much usage , is there any way in which i can give priority to some process or decrease my CPU usage .

Comment: Go into your distribution's system monitor and adjust the priorities for the relevant processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `nice` command from the command line shell to change the priority of a process.

`man nice` and `man renice` should give you the information you need.